# Pressure beneath the Ocean with Neglect to Compressibility

Tags: fluid-mechanics

For a National Board Exam Review:

> What is the pressure 7000ft below the water surface of the ocean?
>   Neglect compressibility.

Answer is 512000psf

$${ P_2 = P_1 + \gamma h }$$
$${ 14.7 \frac{lb_f}{in^2} * (\frac{ 12in }{ 1 ft})^2 = P_1 + (62.4 \frac{lb_f}{ft^3}) 7000ft }$$

I get: 434683.2 psf

Am I using right formula? Is there better approach?

Comment: Did the question specify whether the ocean water was saline or not? The density of sea water is higher than that of fresh water. http://www.windows2universe.org/earth/Water/density.html

Comment: @Fred nope but all the other problems i just solved assumed a 1.03 specific gravity of saltwater...

Comment: I did a quick calculation and I would say even highly saline water would not be enough to reach that pressure.

Comment: 512000 psf is correct if the depth is 8000 ft (adding atmospheric pressure, that is).